# Passing additional arguments to `odeint` from `torchdiffeq` to solve an IVP

Tags: python, pytorch, ode, solver, numerical-integration

In Python I use the package `torchdiffeq` (as provided [here](https://github.com/rtqichen/torchdiffeq)) to solve initial value problems. Given an arbitrary function `f(y, t, omega)`, I am wondering how to pass this additional argument `omega` to the `odeint` solver? From the documentation, I see that I can specify options such as the `step_size`, but I can't figure out how to pass additional arguments that are not the function `y` itself or the time vector `t`. Basically, something like

`sol = odeint(f, x0, t, method='euler', args=(omega))`.

Does any use `torchdiffeq` on a regular basis and can help me out here?

Comment: You need to pass a list in `args`, that means there must be at least one comma, `args=(omega,)`, to distinguish from simple parentheses around the variable that have no effect here. Otherwise if `omega` itself can be interpreted as list, it gets unpacked for the argument list of `f`, and `f` gets too many arguments.

Comment: The above applies to scipy's `odeint`. For the function in the package, there is no internal provision for extra arguments, thus you would have to use lambda expressions like `odeint(lambda t,y: f(t,y,omega),...` as wrapper. See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+solve_ivp+args for a (resolved) similar situation with scipy's new interface `solve_ivp`.

Comment: this works perfectly fine, thank you @LutzLehmann. Can you post it as an answer, so I can accept it?